# Neo4j: Does the Windows Service Wrapper actually log anything?

Tags: windows, logging, neo4j, wrapper

I'm trying to debug the service wrapper for Neo4j Community Server and no matter what I've tried there is never a log file generated.  Does the Windows-Wrapper actually generate log entries? The documentation references the neo4j-wrapper but not the windows-wrapper.

OS: Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2

Neo4j: 2.1.4 or 2.1.7 Community

I changed the logging levels to ALL everywhere I could and the only log files generated are /data/neo4j.0.0.log which seems to only contain information about the HTTP endpoint and /data/graph.db/messages.log which has no references to the wrapper.  I expected to find a log file called /data/log/windows-wrapper.0.0.log

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

windows-wrapper.logging.properties

```
    # Properties file which configures the operation of the JDK logging facility.

    # The system will look for this config file, first using a System property
    # specified at startup:
    #
    # >java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myLoggingConfigFilePath
    #
    # If this property is not specified, then the config file is retrieved from its
    # default location at:
    # JDK_HOME/jre/lib/logging.properties

    # Global logging properties.
    # ------------------------------------------
    # The set of handlers to be loaded upon startup.
    # Comma-separated list of class names.
    # (? LogManager docs say no comma here, but JDK example has comma.)
    #handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
    handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler

    # Default global logging level.
    # Loggers and Handlers may override this level
    # SERVERE, INFO, FINE, FINEST
    .level=ALL

    # Loggers
    # ------------------------------------------
    # Loggers are usually attached to packages.
    # Here, the level for each package is specified.
    # The global level is used by default, so levels specified here simply act as
    # an override.
    org.neo4j.server.level=ALL

    # Handlers
    # -----------------------------------------

    # --- ConsoleHandler ---
    # Override of global logging level
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=org.neo4j.server.logging.SimpleConsoleFormatter
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.filter=org.neo4j.server.logging.NeoLogFilter

    # --- FileHandler ---
    # Override of global logging level
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL

    # Naming style for the output file (the output file is placed in the directory
    # defined by the "user.home" System property):
    #     "/" the local pathname separator
    #    "%t" the system temporary directory
    #    "%h" the value of the "user.home" system property
    #    "%g" the generation number to distinguish rotated logs
    #    "%u" a unique number to resolve conflicts
    #    "%%" translates to a single percent sign "%"
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=data/log/windows-wrapper.%u.%g.log

    # Specifies whether the FileHandler should append onto any existing files
    # (defaults to false):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true

    # Limiting size of output file in bytes (10M):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000

    # Number of output files to cycle through, by appending an integer to the base
    # file name:
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=10

    # The name of the character set encoding to use (defaults to the default
    # platform encoding):
    #java.util.logging.FileHandler.encoding=

    # Style of output (Simple or XML):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

logging.properties

```
    # Properties file which configures the operation of the JDK
    # logging facility.

    # The system will look for this config file, first using
    # a System property specified at startup:
    #
    # >java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myLoggingConfigFilePath
    #
    # If this property is not specified, then the config file is
    # retrieved from its default location at:
    # JDK_HOME/jre/lib/logging.properties

    # Global logging properties.
    # ------------------------------------------
    # The set of handlers to be loaded upon startup.
    # Comma-separated list of class names.
    # (? LogManager docs say no comma here, but JDK example has comma.)
    handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
    #handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

    # Default global logging level.
    # Loggers and Handlers may override this level
    # SEVERE, INFO, FINE, FINEST
    .level=ALL

    # Loggers
    # ------------------------------------------
    # Loggers are usually attached to packages.
    # Here, the level for each package is specified.
    # The global level is used by default, so levels specified here simply act as
    # an override.
    org.neo4j.server.level=ALL

    # Handlers
    # -----------------------------------------

    # --- ConsoleHandler ---
    # Override of global logging level
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=org.neo4j.server.logging.SimpleConsoleFormatter
    #java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.filter=org.neo4j.server.logging.NeoLogFilter

    # --- FileHandler ---
    # Override of global logging level
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL

    # Naming style for the output file (the output file is placed in the directory
    # defined by the "user.home" System property):
    #     "/" the local pathname separator
    #    "%t" the system temporary directory
    #    "%h" the value of the "user.home" system property
    #    "%g" the generation number to distinguish rotated logs
    #    "%u" a unique number to resolve conflicts
    #    "%%" translates to a single percent sign "%"
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=data/log/neo4j.%u.%g.log

    # Specifies whether the FileHandler should append onto any existing files
    # (defaults to false):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true

    # Limiting size of output file in bytes (10M):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000

    # Number of output files to cycle through, by appending an integer to the base
    # file name:
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=10

    # The name of the character set encoding to use (defaults to the default
    # platform encoding):
    #java.util.logging.FileHandler.encoding=

    # Style of output (Simple or XML):
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was the last person to make changes to that particular part of the codebase, I'll attempt an awswer: yes, we do do logging. Here, for example: https://github.com/neo4j/windows-wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/wrapper/NeoServiceWrapper.java#L49-60

That is only in the case where you launch it as a console app though, it seems. And I am not sure if the library we use does logging of it's own. And I have to admit that last I looked at this I didn't notice whether logging was indeed working or not.

So, I have not got any concrete advice for you at the moment. I'll make sure to make a note in the backlog to go over this. Meanwhile if you get a breakthrough let us know!

- Lasse

Comment: Thanks Lasse. Almost 2 years since you made changes too.  I suspect I may be sending some PRs to that repo in the near future :-)

Comment: Lasse,  I don't suppose you used IntelliJ went you tried building the wrapper.  I'm having difficulty getting the artefacts to generate properly.  I can generate the JAR but it doesn't have the manifest inside it.  If you have your project files still around, can I get a copy of it?

Thanks,
 Glenn

Comment: @glennsarti I have pushed an update for the pom and ran it, it at least now generates a manifest on my machine: https://github.com/neo4j/windows-wrapper/commit/897d0685aa7520de260994801c9d582b29c806ee - does it work for you now?

And the manifest I got is here: https://gist.github.com/lassewesth/dad9a7e2c7a85746e115

Comment: Thanks Lasse.  I'm now getting a Maven package that creates the Jar for me.  I had to be a little cheeky though.  The ClasspathParserTests were failing to what looks like a simple backslash vs forward slash problem.

shouldFindJarsAtMultipleLevels)
Expected: is "\"-classpath\" \"...r\663f4d5d-c1c3-4f70-8eed-3768b19b0d04/lib/aneo4jlibrary.jar;...
     but: was "\"-classpath\" \"...r\663f4d5d-c1c3-4f70-8eed-3768b19b0d04\lib\aneo4jlibrary.jar;...

I'll look at those tests after I work through the logging.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Just raised a GitHub issue about the logging config.  Looks like it's using the default working directory instead of the one specified on the java command line.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4142